# How to display component when page load on reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Thanks for the great job here. I am new on reactJS and building my application view layer with it.

I am trying to make a header with a message load 3 seconds after the page loads completely and I have no idea here to start.

Google search was not fruitful so I am asking our developer community for some help.

Here is what I want to do : When page finish loading I want a header to load 2 seconds after the page is complete loading.

Please be nice , I am a newbie.

Comment: How do you manage your application state? Conceptually you just need to add a setTimeout on page load which modifies your app state...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
       super();
       this.state = {
          showHeader: false
       }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
       setTimeout(() => this.setState({showHeader: true}), 2000);
    }

    render() {
       return (
           this.state.showHeader && <div>Header</div>
       );
     }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Home/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: can you put this into a sandbox so I can test and see how can I implement it into my code ?

Comment: okay looks like I have a beginning of something here. What if I want to load a specific className into my comment ? what parameter should I change ?

Comment: Just make it a state and use conditional rendering. Something like: `className={this.state.showClass ? 'class-name' : ''}`

Comment: okay thanks I managed to make it work with your tip and some JS tricks